# How to check if page is loaded from cache in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have question from interview "How to check if page is loaded from cache in magento 2",
thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your chrome console goes to network, right click on the main section. Select **Header options** -> **Response Headers** -> **Manage Header Columns...** -> Add custom header with name **x-magento-cache-debug**

x-magento-cache-debug displays on page load cache **MISS** or **HIT**.

**HIT** Means page is loaded from cache.